# How to maintain state in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

It is kind of a multi-step form. I need to bring back the user to the step he's left off the previous time. There is no user login.
I'm stuck with "whether it is possible to maintain user details without login?!".
 Can anyone please tell me what would be the best way to do it in rails?!

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of going about it. You can either store the half-filled form on your server or you can store the half-filled form on the user's browser in `LocalStorage`.

#### 1) Server Method

When the user clicks next step you can have an AJAX call send the data to server. Your server can store this in a table and return the `id` back to the browser. Store this `id` in browser's `LocalStorage` or in cookies.

When the user comes to your form next time, check if your `id` is present in your choice of storage, if yes then fetch the data from server and move the user to next step of the form.

> You might need to think about security implications in this method as well. If a user can figure out you are storing `id`s and get the fetch URL of half-filled form, they can iterate over them and fetch other user's form as well. So you might store something other than `id` and still use this approach.

#### 2) LocalStorage method

Everything is same as the previous approach but we are not using server to store the form. Simply use browser to store the form and fetch when the user comes on the website later. `LocalStorage` is a persistent storage so it'll also be available when the user re-opens their browser.

I hope this clears your problem here.

Answer (score 1):

[Wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) is `ruby gem` that is used to make step wizard forms. I think it should help you.

Comment: yeah that gem helped me out to build a cool multi-step form, but i'm in need of the way to maintain the user details if the user discontinues the form and come back again after a while. How to maintain the state of the form for that user. (In other words, how to provide the step where he'd left off, when he comes back)

Comment: You can save the step name till when user has completed info form in user table and when user comes back you can start from the next step.

Comment: it would work. thanks for the suggestion @titan But, still can you please clarify me that, is it possible to extend this even if there is no user login?

Comment: You could save `ip ` of the user from where it is opening the web page. But that would not help if user accesses site from a different place or `ip`